# VBScript to create CSV from text file

Tags: string, csv, batch-file, vbscript

I would like to create a CSV text file from some strings delimited by some spaces, but the amount of spaces is not known. I.e:

```
fname lname         Degree          Test3
City                experience

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

fname2 lname2           Degree2         Test32
City2               experience2

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

fname3 lname3           Degree3         Test33
City3               experience3

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I would like the output to be like

```
fname,lname,Degree,Test3,City,Experience  
fname2,lname2,Degree2,Test32,City2,Experience2
fname3,lname3,Degree3,Test33,City,Experience3
```

Note that the variables used are not fixed width and will change. How should I do to get all the different strings into actual variables? I was able to do something half working in Batch though:

Batch1

```
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    for /F "tokens=*" %%I in (C:\Users\bonhkarl01\Desktop\Test.txt) do (

    set str=%%I
    set str=!str:           =,!
    set str=!str: =,!
    set str=!str:   =!
    echo.!str! >> "C:\Users\bonhkarl01\Desktop\Test2.txt"
    )

    findstr /v /b /c:"-----------------------------------------------------------------" C:\Users\bonhkarl01\Desktop\Test2.txt > C:\Users\bonhkarl01\Desktop\Test3.txt
```

Batch2

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in (C:\Users\bonhkarl01\Desktop\Test3.txt) do (set "string=!string!%%a,")
set "string=%string:~0,-1%"
echo.%string%> "C:\Users\bonhkarl01\Desktop\Test4.txt"
pause
```

Would give me the following input:

```
fname,lname,Degree,Test3,City,experience,fname2,lname2,Degree2,Test32,City2,experience2,fname3,lname3,Degree3,Test33,City3,experience3
```

But still the width is known in the batch.

Comment: You need to start coding it yourself, and if you have a specific problem, you can ask that and we might be able to help.  We're not going to write the code for you.

Comment: I gotta say i know how batch file works pretty well. But not for the VBScript. Is there a way we could make this work with batch file?  Use   SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    for /F "tokens=*" %%I in (C:\Users\bonhkarl01\Desktop\Test.txt) do (

    set str=%%I
    set str=!str:NOT FIXED=,!
    set str=!str:NOT FIXED=,!
    set str=!str:NOT FIXED=!
    echo.!str! >> "C:\Users\bonhkarl01\Desktop\Test2.txt"
    )

    findstr /v /b /c:"-----------------------------------------------------------------" C:\Users\bonhkarl01\Desktop\Test2.txt > C:\Users\bonhkarl01\Desktop\Test3.txt

Comment: I don't know batch at all.  I would say you should start by googling how to code vbscript for beginners, or get a book.  This site is not going to be much help in teaching you how to code; that's just not how it works.

Comment: Would adding another post about Batch file do the work? Not that i don't want to learn VBS, but the schedule to get this work is a bit tight! Any tips on VBS for learning it?  Thanks!

Comment: That's kinda like asking for tips on learning a spoken language.  There's no tips, you just have to learn it.  Like anything else, you can learn the basics really quick, but it takes years to "master", and even then, you're never truly a master.  Just build upon your existing knowledge of stuff and go from there.

Comment: I'll do that then. Thanks

Comment: Why are you searching for `--------` although this does not occur anywhere in your text files, according to your sample data??

Comment: Thanks roryap. Just learning VBScript. Such a nice script code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your answer! It would have work. I just got a new files from the provider... he kind of changed everything! Here is the output:

(File begin)
69

FirstName LastName

Gatineau, QC (42km)

```
Universitaire 

2016-02-17
```

69

FirstName LastName

Gatineau, QC (43km)

Universitaire

2016-02-17

(File end)

And I was able to get to it with VBScript.

```
For t = 0 to uBound(FileContentsAray)
    If Len(FileContentsAray(t)) > 0 Then
        LineCount = LineCount + 1
        If LineCount = 2 Then 
            unnom = split(FileContentsAray(t)," ")



        if uBound(unnom) > 1 Then
            if ubound(unnom) = 4 Then
                WriteInFile NewFile, unnom(0) & " " & unnom(1)  & "," & unnom(2)& " " & unnom(3)
            else
                WriteInFile NewFile, unnom(0) & " " & unnom(1) & "," & unnom(2)
            end if
        else
            if uBound(unnom) = 0 Then 
                WriteInFile NewFile, unnom(0)
            else 
                WriteInFile NewFile, unnom(0) & "," & unnom(1)
            end if

        end if

        End if
        If LineCount = 5 Then LineCount = 0

    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question have a big problem that, unfortunately, is very usual: you have not *described* your problem, you just shown some example data that surely does *not* represent the real data. When the specifications of a problem are incomplete we just can *guess* the missing info, and in this case it is frequent that the OP reply: "Your program does not work with my real data". In order to solve this problem, I *assumed* that each group of data in your files is separated by a line with 65 dashes (the same you used in your example code). This is the data file I used:

```
fname lname         Degree          Test3
City                experience

-----------------------------------------------------------------

fname2 lname2           Degree2         Test32
City2               experience2

-----------------------------------------------------------------

fname3 lname3           Degree3         Test33
City3               experience3

-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the Batch code that solve the problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "line="
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (Test.txt) do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do (
      if "%%b" equ "-----------------------------------------------------------------" (
         echo !line:~1!
         set "line="
      ) else (
         set "line=!line!,%%b"
      )
   )
)) > output.txt
```

And this is the output:

```
fname,lname,Degree,Test3,City,experience
fname2,lname2,Degree2,Test32,City2,experience2
fname3,lname3,Degree3,Test33,City3,experience3
```